# 1S Li-Ion BMS Design

Tags: lithium-ion, constant-current, over-voltage-protection, bms, over-discharge

I want to use AP6633 Protection IC along with MCP73833 Charging IC for 1S Lithium-Ion Battery. The issue is pinout of AP6633. I really dont have any idea how to connect AP6633 Pins to MCP73833, More specifically the Vm Pin. I am attaching datasheets of Both ICs. Screenshot of their Application diagrams are also attached. [image: AP]
[image: MCP73833]
https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/22005b.pdf
https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2108150030_ALLPOWER-ShenZhen-Quan-Li-Semiconductor-AP6683_C2849565.pdf

Comment: anyone to look into it?